# Container not extending to the footer

Tags: html, height, containers, footer

I have been visiting this site for years but I never ask for help and always eventually get things going on my own but this time I am baffled. The link to my site http://keigirl.com/cannon/contact.htm css code http://keigirl.com/cannon/css/contact.css I will post it here is need be but I didn't want to have a lengthy post. I validated the page and css and everything pass, I added the

```
<-- * { margin: 0;...  html, body {    margin:0;    padding:0;    height:100%;
```

... the container is inside a div with id name "page" that is 100% width and the footer is below the "page" div and is also 100% width and is 100px in height. I cleared both on the footer but it's not working. It looks fine from my computer. It's my mobile device where I see the very big gap. Since most of the people I know that access my gallery use mobile devices it's very important to me to get this right. I've tried for two days straight for hours to no avail. If anyone can help I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your site with http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ and on every Table/Mobile phone everything is ok.
Btw. Your header has very low resolution. On my screen 1680x1050 is quite pixeled.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Sorry for the delay. I totally forgot I posted this question.